# Как вытянуть значения с таблицы Benchmark?

Tags: память, c#-7.0, benchmark

предположим у меня есть таблица:

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| WithStringBuilder | 153.8 ns | 0.37 ns | 0.33 ns | 0.0739 | 464 B |
| WithConcatenation | 167.8 ns | 0.73 ns | 0.57 ns | 0.1235 | 776 B |
| WithInterpolation | 165.7 ns | 0.40 ns | 0.35 ns | 0.1235 | 776 B |

как мне вытунять в отдельную переменную Allocated?

Comment: Таблица у вас где и в чём? `HTML` где-то в интернете?

Comment: Достаточно открыть [документацию](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/configs/exporters.html)... Уважаемый, вы очень рано взялись за это все, ибо видно, что вы не знаете даже как работать на конкретном языке, как искать информацию.